# I am working on this code of Google maps on codepen

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

It works perfect on codepen but when I download it to my computer, it doesnt work. I am trying to figure this out for hours, what could be the reason that it works on codepen but not on my computer browser?
I know I am doing something very stupid that I am not realizing. All the other google map code that I have work just fine

```
    <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false'> </script>

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }


      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 40%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #ffb052;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        color: #444;
        font-family: Arial;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="panel">
    <b>Start (A): </b>

    <input id="start" onchange="calcRoute();" />

    <b>End (B): </b>
    <select id="end" onchange="">


      <option value="sydney, AU">Sydney</option>
      <option value="melbourne, AU">Melbourne</option>
      <option value="-33.751873,150.698227">Penrith</option>

    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="calcRoute();" />
    <b>Distance:</b> <span id='total'></span>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>


    <script>
    var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

// Sites
var penrith = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.751873,150.698227);
var charlestown = new google.maps.LatLng(-32.963991,151.694228);










function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var australia = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.274398, 133.775136);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: australia
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);



    var penrithMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: penrith,
      map: map,
      icon: 'https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=..|fb8d32|000000',
      title: 'Penrith Club'
      });


    var charlestownMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: charlestown,
      map: map,
      icon: 'https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=..|fb8d32|000000',
      title: 'Charlestown Club'
      });




  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  // Enables Distance Calc
    google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.directions);
  });



}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}


function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var total = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
  }
  total = total / 1000.
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total + " km";
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/falak786/pen/MEWyzB

Comment: You can update your post instead of adding comments. Others might important info if you don't.

Comment: What errors do you get on your computer?

Comment: I just noticed that it wasn't working on the mozilla browser only. And it was working on chrome but only partially. Does maps Api v3 has to do anything with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this works, only copy & paste, cheers.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         html, body, #map-canvas {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px
         }
         #panel {
         position: absolute;
         top: 5px;
         left: 40%;
         margin-left: -180px;
         z-index: 5;
         background-color: #ffb052;
         padding: 5px;
         border: 1px solid #999;
         color: #444;
         font-family: Arial;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="panel">
         <b>Start (A): </b>
         <b>End (B): </b>
         <select id="end" onchange="calcRoute();">
            <option value="47.2970596,11.51218330000006">Absam</option>
            <option value="47.52602899999999,11.706817199999932">Achenkirch</option>
            <option value="47.31316,10.998730000000023">Affenhausen </option>
            <option value="47.3990938,11.943168199999946">Alpbach</option>
            <option value="47.2624249,11.462091200000032">Ampass</option>
            <option value="47.20705,10.761870000000044">Arzl im Pitztal
            </option>
            <option value="47.26660109999999,11.895328199999994">Aschau im Zillertal
            </option>
            <option value="47.3112528,11.198198899999966">Auland bei Seelfeld
            </option>
            <option value="47.19569,11.302649999999971">Axamer Lizum</option>
            <option value="47.2303585,11.279548999999975">Axams</option>
            <option value="47.5108796,12.118506600000046">Bad Haring
            </option>
            <option value="47.2970596,11.51218330000006">Bad Tölz über Garmisch</option>
            <option value="47.30548899999999,10.962690000000066">Barwies</option>
            <option value="47.3001526,11.563272299999994">Baumkirchen</option>
            <option value="47.40969,10.748219899999981">Berwang</option>
            <option value="47.15991,9.808210000000031">Bludenz</option>
            <option value="46.7340955,11.288801499999977">Bozen</option>
            <option value="47.50075,9.742309999999975">Bregenz</option>
            <option value="47.1525,15.046010000000024">Breitenbach</option>
            <option value="47.0094541,11.509094199999936">Brenner
            </option>
         </select>
         <button type="button" onclick="calcRoute();">Calculate</button>
         <b>Distance:</b> <span id='total'></span>
      </div>
      <div id="map-canvas"></div>
      <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false'> </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var directionsDisplay;
         var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
         var map;
         
         // Sites
         var penrith = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.751873,150.698227);
         var charlestown = new google.maps.LatLng(-32.963991,151.694228);
         
         function initialize() {
         directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
         var australia = new google.maps.LatLng(47.2692124,11.404102400000056);
         var mapOptions = {
         zoom:4,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         center: australia
         };
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
         
         directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
         // Enables Distance Calc
         google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
         computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.directions);
         });
         
         }
         
         function calcRoute() {
         var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(47.257372,11.350713000000042);
         var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
         var request = {
         origin:pointA,
         destination:end,
         travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
         };
         directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
         }
         });
         }
         
         function computeTotalDistance(result) {
         var total = 0;
         var myroute = result.routes[0];
         for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
         total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
         }
         total = total / 1000;
         document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total + " km";
         }
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      </script>
   </body>
   <html>
```